# C# instantiate class with varying "child" class

Tags: c#

I have a class that has some derived classes. That works.

I want to instantiate the "parent" class. Got that far...

But I want to instantiate it with one of the "child" classes, and then possibly change that "child" class later. Maybe the deriving is inappropriate here.

Take the following example:

```
public class Unicorn {
    public string Horn { get; set; }
    public Unicorn(){

    }
}

public class BadUnicorn : Unicorn{
    public string Rainbow()
    {
        return "dark rainbow";
    }

}
public class GoodUnicorn : Unicorn{
    public string Rainbow()
    {
        return "light rainbow";
    }
}
```

I could instantiate one of the children, but then if I change one from "good" to "bad", I would have to re-instantiate. And maybe that's just the way it is, and that would be an acceptable answer if that's all there is to it.

I rather want to instantiate a Unicorn, and then be able to change it from Good to Bad to maintain information stored on that Unicorn, but have access to the current methods and properties of the "child" class.

That way when I call `Unicorn.Rainbow()` it calls the desired method of the "child" class.

I'm a little new to C#, is there a pattern that fits this bill?

Comment: You cannot change an instance of class from one to another. Once it is created it is always the same type.

Comment: It's looking as though polymorphism may be what I'm looking for... looking into it, will post here if I accomplish what I want

Comment: Instead of making GoodUnicorn & BadUnicorn different class, just make them as enum properties in Unicorn. Then when you call Rainbow, use the [delegate dictionary](http://joelabrahamsson.com/invoking-methods-based-on-a-parameter-without-if-else-statements-in-c/) pattern

Comment: @Martheen Please post that as an answer. That is beautiful, and the example is the exact train of thought I had.

Comment: @Martheen - Can you explain how using an `enum` relates to the delegate dictionary pattern?

Comment: @Enigmativity posted an answer about it.

Answer (score 3):

You can't do what you want with polymorphism. You cannot change an instance of class from one to another. Once it is created it is always the same type.

You can use composition though.

Here's what you'd need to do:

```
public class Unicorn
{
    public string Horn { get; set; }
    public Unicorn(Rainbow rainbow)
    {
        _rainbow = rainbow;
    }

    public void SetRainbow(Rainbow rainbow)
    {
        _rainbow = rainbow;
    }

    private Rainbow _rainbow;

    public string Rainbow()
    {
        return _rainbow.Colour();
    }
}

public abstract class Rainbow
{
    public abstract string Colour();
}

public class BadRainbow : Rainbow
{
    public override string Colour()
    {
        return "dark rainbow";
    }
}

public class GoodRainbow : Rainbow
{
    public override string Colour()
    {
        return "light rainbow";
    }
}
```

You can test like this:

```
var unicorn = new Unicorn(new GoodRainbow());
Console.WriteLine(unicorn.Rainbow());

unicorn.SetRainbow(new BadRainbow());
Console.WriteLine(unicorn.Rainbow());
```

This outputs:

```
light rainbow
dark rainbow
```

The instance of `Unicorn` stays the same, but you can change the rainbow.

Comment: This is really good too. I'm going to have to play with this and the delegate dictionary method and see which works best in my situation, but right now they're both looking good. Very informative, much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Here's my take on delegate dictionary. While it seems superfluous to use Func instead of just string, if the method have additional functionality like calculation or need parameters, you're covered with Func.

```
public class Unicorn
{
    static Dictionary<Attitude, Func<string>> RainbowByAttitude =
        new Dictionary<Attitude, Func<string>>()
        {
            [Attitude.Bad] = new Func<string>(() => "dark rainbow"),
            [Attitude.Good] = new Func<string>(()=>"light rainbow")

        };
    public string Horn { get; set; }
    public enum Attitude
    {
        Good,Bad
    }
    public Attitude attitude;
    public Unicorn(Attitude attitude)
    {
        this.attitude = attitude;
    }

    public string Rainbow() => RainbowByAttitude[attitude].Invoke();

}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Unicorn unicorn;

        unicorn = new Unicorn(Unicorn.Attitude.Bad);
        Console.WriteLine(unicorn.Rainbow());
        unicorn.attitude = Unicorn.Attitude.Good;
        Console.WriteLine(unicorn.Rainbow());

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems like a state pattern to me like this:

```
public abstract class UnicornState
{
    public abstract UnicornState Change();

    public abstract string Rainbow();
}

public sealed class GoodUnicornState : UnicornState
{
    public override UnicornState Change()
    {
        return new BadUnicornState();
    }

    public override string Rainbow()
    {
        return "light rainbow";
    }
}

public sealed class BadUnicornState : UnicornState
{
    public override UnicornState Change()
    {
        return new GoodUnicornState();
    }

    public override string Rainbow()
    {
        return "dark rainbow";
    }
}

public class Unicorn
{
    public string Horn { get; set; }

    public UnicornState State { get; set; }

    public string Rainbow => State.Rainbow();
}
```

Usage:

```
var u = new Unicorn();
u.State = new GoodUnicornState();
Console.WriteLine(u.Rainbow);

u.State = u.State.Change();
Console.WriteLine(u.Rainbow);
```